# Error in configurating secured-annotations Spring security

Tags: spring-security

I have a problem in configurting :

```
 <sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getLocalName(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Ljava/lang/String
```

There are some incompitable jar files with schema security

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">
```

I am using the following security jar:

spring-security-core-tiger-2.0.4

spring-2.5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may not have the required spring-security dependency (`spring-security-tiger-xxx.jar`).

As per the spring-security-2.0.2 [xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.2.xsd), `secured-annotations` is available.

Comment: Thanks, I have spring-security-core-tiger-2.0.0 jar. Do you think I need to download different version of spring-security-core-tiger jar.

Comment: Please anyone can help me what's the sutitable version spring-security-core-tiger-2.0.0 to avoid the error

Comment: @user813056. Please edit your question and provide the relevant maven snippet of your project - specifically the spring-security related dependencies. Perhaps you have incorrect/incompatible spring-security jar.